# Formatting before encrypting

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

Is formatting a device before encrypting more secure as opposed to encrypting the device without a formatting?

Comment: How do you apply encryption without formatting the partition, I wonder?

Comment: I believe truecrypt has the option to do so

Comment: Can you **prove** that former contents of the device are harmless if leaked? Can you prove there's no **bootkit** on the MBR? Formatting is a matter of discipline and good judgment.

Comment: @DeerHunter you technically install an OS before encrypting it, so it's kind of hard to format it as it won't work anymore :p

Comment: Android has the option of encrypting a device and it does not delete anything on the device, it takes an hour or so.